# How to get the servlet context in a Google Cloud Endpoint method?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a simple Google cloud endpoint. How can I access the context? I'm looking for something similar to `getServletContext()` from `HttpServlet`.

```
@Api
public FooEndpoint {
    @ApiMehod
    public String[] getFiles() {
        // TODO: return files in WEB-INF/data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The servlet context is an [injected type](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types#injected_types). Just include it as a method argument to an endpoint method and the server will fill it in for you. E.g.

```
@Api
public FooEndpoint {
  @ApiMethod
  public String[] getFiles(ServletContext context) {
    // TODO: return files in WEB-INF/data
  }
}
```

You don't need to annotate the argument, and it won't appear in the method stub in the generated client library.